# Sticky sidebar | Problems with content height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I am tring to create a sidebar or section that follows you as you scroll down the page.

It works fine but if height of content shorter than leftsidebar, page became not smooth and structure is broken. How to fix it?!

```js
$(function () {

        var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;

        if (!msie6 && $('.sidebar').offset() != null) {
            var top = $('.sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('.sidebar').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
            var height = $('.sidebar').height();
            var winHeight = $(window).height();
            var footerTop = $('#footer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#footer').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
            var gap = 0;
            $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                // what the y position of the scroll is
                var y = $(this).scrollTop();

                // whether that's below the form
                if (y + winHeight >= top + height + gap && y + winHeight <= footerTop) {
                    // if so, ad the fixed class
                    $('.sidebar').addClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top', winHeight - height - gap + 'px');
                }
                else if (y + winHeight > footerTop) {
                    // if so, ad the fixed class
                    $('.sidebar').addClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top', footerTop - height - y - gap + 'px');
                }
                else {
                    // otherwise remove it
                    $('.sidebar').removeClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top', '0px');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

```css
.scrollable {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .max-height {
        height: 100%;

    }
    .no-overflow {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .sidebar {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            height: 100vh;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1000;
            display: block;
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
    }
    .main {
        padding-top: 20px;
        height:auto;

    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .main {
            padding-right: 20px;
            padding-left: 20px;

        }
    }
    .table{
        font-size:x-small;
    }
    .HeaderStyle th{
        text-align:center; /*Заголовки в таблице стоят по центру*/
        background-color:#FFDEAD;
    }

    #wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #contentHolder{
        position:relative;
    }
    #header,#footer {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCFFFF;
        color: #000000;
        height: 150px;
        width: 100%;
        clear:both;
        font-size:3em;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .leftsidebarfixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">...</div>
  <div class="container-fluid max-height no-overflow">
      <div class ="row max-height">
          <div id="contentHolder">
              <form runat="server">
                <!--sidebar-->
                <div runat="server" class="col-sm-3 sidebar">       

                </div>    
                <!--MAIN CONTENT-->
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 main scrollable">
                    
                </div>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

**Problem:**

[image]

Comment: In a JSFIDDLE, the code comes out to have sideways structure, is this your problem?

Comment: Hello @sbswim At the end of the post you can see picture with my problem. Can you check my code pls. Whats wrong I did?